# Can I do a lazy take with a long parameter?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Stream.take takes an int as a parameter.  I want to define a take that takes a long instead- is this possible without using takeWhile to manage a counter?

Comment: So long as you don't keep any reference to the head while you're iterating over the stream, that's correct. But if that's the case then maybe you'd be better off just using an `Iterator`(and if you want your code to be more generic, just work on a `TraversableOnce`, which `Iterator` extends).

Comment: I'm going with takeWhile with a counter for now.  It's a trivial amount of memory (counter) to manage myself, just figured the main collections lib would support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know that it's at least doable (but is it a good idea?), you can enrich `Stream` with an alternate version of `take`:

```
implicit class StreamOps[A](val stream: Stream[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def take(n: Long): Stream[A] = {
    if (n <= 0 || stream.isEmpty) Stream.empty
    else if (n == 1) Stream.cons(stream.head, Stream.empty)
    else Stream.cons(stream.head, stream.tail take n-1)
  }
}
```