# Extract range of bytes from file in Scala

Tags: scala, fileinputstream

I have a binary file that I need to extract some range of bytes from: `start: Long` - `end: Long`. I need `Long` because there are several gigagbytes. My app needs to give the result back as a `ByteString`. I tried

```
val content: Array[Byte] = Array()
val stream: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file: File)
stream.skip(start)
stream.read(content, 0, end-start)
```

but already I cannot use `Long` in `read`, only `Int` (is this a bug? `skip` is ok with `Long`...). Also I would need to convert the result to `ByteString`. I would love to do this, too:

```
val stream: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file: File)
stream.skip(start)
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(stream)
```

but how do I tell it where to end? `stream` has no method `takeWhile` or `take`. Then I tried

```
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file: File)
source.drop(start).take(end-start)
```

Again, only `Int` in `drop`...

How can I do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883876/can-i-do-a-lazy-take-with-a-long-parameter

Comment: With that I was trying to implement a correct response to a byte-range request in Play, but since recently Play seems to have implemented that, and documents it in "Working with public assets"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input, long size)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream,%20long))

```
val stream = new FileInputStream(file)
stream.skip(start)
val bytesICareAbout = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream, end-start)
// form the ByteString from bytesICareAbout
```

**Note** this will throw if `end - start` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, for a good reason! You wouldn't want a 2GB array to be allocated in-memory.

If for some reason your `end - start > Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you should definitely avoid allocating a single ByteString to represent the data. Instead, you should do something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.input.BoundedInputStream

val stream = new FileInputStream(file)
stream.skip(start)
val boundedStream = new BoundedInputStream(stream, start - end)
```

Comment: Oh, I did not see that there was a second constructor, thanks, it works !